# how to give relative path in nlog.config asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

How to give relative path in filename instead of hard coded value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- targets to write to-->
    <targets>
    <!-- write to file-->
        <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File" 
        filename="C:\BotFamework\OasisDev-src\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/>
    </targets>
    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target-->
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues/errors are you getting?

Comment: i tried giving relative path using filename=~\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log

Comment: also .\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log  , ..\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log, /Logs/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log     But the log file is not getting generated,When i give hardcoded complete path only then the file is getting generated

Comment: Please update your question to include these as it clutters the comments and makes it harder for future viewers to following along :)

Answer (score 2):

Specify the fileName in Nlog.Config as

```
fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}\..\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
```

Also, Add the NLog.Web from NuGet Packages

Comment: like filename="${aspnet-appbasepath}..\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log" ? as i want them to be palced in folder logs

Comment: If so, what was the result !

Comment: ilename="${aspnet-appbasepath}\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/>   didnt work!

Comment: missing double dots in your fileName "${xyz}..\Logs\xyz.log"

Comment: still file didnot get generated. I gave filename="${aspnet-appbasepath}..\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/>    Logs fodler & nlog.config are under same root folder

Comment: filename="${aspnet-appbasepath}.\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/> It worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my nlog.config of .NET Core 3.1 API project I set the targets as

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}\logs\nlog-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
</targets>
```

and I have got installed NLog.Web and NLog.Web.AspNetCore.